# Invoke-VMscript doesnt work as expected

Tags: powershell

Here is my script:

```
$ScriptText = $Adapter = Get-NetAdapter | 
    Select-Object InterfaceDescription,Name | %{
        if ($Adapter.InterfaceDescription -match "vmxnet3") {
             Get-NetAdapter -Name $Adapter.Name | Rename-NetAdapter -NewName "LAN"
        }
    }

Invoke-VMScript –VM "DC01” -guestuser “administrator” -guestpassword “password” -ScriptText $ScriptText
```

The following error is produced:

```
Invoke-VMScript : 26-8-2015 11:34:40    Invoke-VMScript        
Value cannot be found for the mandatory parameter ScriptText
At line:7 char:1
+ Invoke-VMScript –VM "DC01” -guestuser “administrator” -guestpassword “password”  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-VMScript], VimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Core_BaseCmdlet_UnknownError,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.InvokeVmScript
```

The string `$ScriptText` should contain the commands between the quotes.

```
$ScriptText = "Get-NetAdapter | Select InterfaceDescription,Name | % {if($_.InterfaceDescription -match 'vmxnet3') {Get-NetAdapter -Name $_.Name | Rename-NetAdapter -NewName ""LAN""}}"
```

The `Invoke-VMScript` logs in via the supplied credentials and runs the script.

```
Invoke-VMScript –VM "DC01” -guestuser “administrator” -guestpassword “password” -ScriptText $ScriptText
```

At this moment I have the following error:

```
% : The term '.InterfaceDescription' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:56
+ & {Get-NetAdapter | Select InterfaceDescription,Name | % {if(.InterfaceDescripti ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.InterfaceDescription:String) [ForEach-Object], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

Comment: What is the value of `$ScriptText`?

Comment: Richard, ScriptText is a kind of a script block. The code will run inside a virtual machine. The Invoke-VMScript let the script run within the Virtual Machine.

Comment: Yes, that is obvious: but the error is saying it does not have a value. (And I note the [VMWare docs](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/windowstoolkit/wintk40u1/html/Invoke-VMScript.html) say it must be a string not a script block).

Comment: Richard, Get-NetAdapter | Select InterfaceDescription,Name | % {if($_.InterfaceDescription -match 'vmxnet3') {Get-NetAdapter -Name $_.Name | Rename-NetAdapter -NewName ""LAN""}} is working on a Windows 2012R2 server without problems. It renames the nic to LAN.

Comment: The string must be this line of text: Get-NetAdapter | Select InterfaceDescription,Name | % {if($_.InterfaceDescription -match 'vmxnet3') {Get-NetAdapter -Name $_.Name | Rename-NetAdapter -NewName ""LAN""}} thanks for youre time Marcel

Comment: Please add the extra information to the question (too hard to read in comments);

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use HereString for the Script Text like this:

```
$ScriptText = @'
$Adapter = Get-NetAdapter | 
       Select-Object InterfaceDescription,Name | 
       %{if ($Adapter.InterfaceDescription -match "vmxnet3")               
         {Get-NetAdapter -Name $Adapter.Name | Rename-NetAdapter -NewName "LAN"}
        }
'@

$GuestCredential = Get-Credential
Invoke-VMScript –VM "DC01” -GuestCredential $GuestCredential -ScriptText $ScriptText
```

However, an easier Approach i think is to use WMI,

```
$Adapter = gwmi win32_networkadapter -ComputerName DC01 | ? {$_.Description -match "vmxnet3"}
$Adapter.NetConnectionID = "LAN"
$Adapter.Put()
```